# Don't render null from JavaScript object's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for most efficient way to output `empty string` instead of `"null"` for `null` values. Is there a way to do this **without** conditional statements (i.e. `if` or ternary (`? :`) operator).

Code sample as follows:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append(item.PhoneNumber);
}
```

when `item.PhoneNumber is null`, the page renders with a string "**null**" inside the `SearchResults div`, instead I wanted to be **empty**.

Comment: Why? Why would you want to avoid evaluating your variables before output?

Comment: I thought there would be a more efficient way, i.e. some sort of built-in function. I'm surprised there isn't one in either JavaScript or jQuery :(

Comment: Well, the `||` (`or`) operator does this, but the variable's still evaluated first, just without an explicit `if` or ternary.

Comment: The conversion of `null` to string is [hard coded at implementation level to be `"null"`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) and cannot be changed by user-made code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append(item.PhoneNumber || "");
}
```

With `$.trim` (unexpectedly converts `null` and `undefined` to empty string):

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append($.trim(item.PhoneNumber));
}
```

Unexpected because it's both unintuitive and undocumented.

Comment: Upvoting because we came up with the same answer at around the same time and, also, because I don't understand the down-vote.

Answer (score 8):

If you're really determined not to use an `if` or ternary to evaluate the variable, then there is the possibility of using the `||` operator:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append(item.PhoneNumber || '');
}
```

But, honestly, just use a conditional operator, it's what they're meant for, and helps enforce a certain amount of security in your script's execution and output.

Comment: At most I'd go for a `=== null` ternarny but not if statement :P

Comment: I agree with the your approach to the evaluation method; but I'd still, regardless, explicitly evaluate the variable/return value, rather than relying on the above method (albeit it works, it just feels... *wrong*, slightly).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append(item.PhoneNumber?item.PhoneNumber:"");
}
```

Comment: From the OPs question *Is there a way to do this **without** conditional statements (i.e. if or ? :)*

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the question specifically requests avoiding the ternary operator (as well as the `if`), though it's not referred to by name; so is easily missed.

Answer (score -1):

Without JQuery:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  return $("div#SearchResults").append([item.PhoneNumber].join(''));
}
```

Comment: _'Without jQuery'_, but it's still jQuery?